# Linux - Ubuntu Move Files from Multiple Locations of same name to a Common Location

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file-management

I would like to find files and move them to a new folder. The files are scattered across multiple locations but always in the same name folder e,g,

\mnt\Music\folder_a\target_folder

\mnt\Music\folder_b\target_folder

\mnt\Music\folder_c\target_folder

So I would like to find all the files in all the target_folder locations and move them to a common folder.

How can this be achieved please?

Answer (score 1):

Few ways of doing it but the simplest is using wildcards in the path

You can do `mv /mnt/music/folder_*/*.mp3`

and it'd match every mp3 in any folder starting with 'folder_'.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately folder_a, folder_b etc can be any text with no predictable structure ( I should have made this clear in the question, sorry). Is there a way to approach that?

Comment: You could either use /mnt/music/*/*.mp3  (to have _any_ folder name in there) or using find -name '*.mp3' /mnt/music/

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
mv \mnt\Music\*\target_folder\* common_folder
```

This will move everything from the desired folders, but not choke if accidentally a **file** (not **folder**) with name `target_folder` were to exist.